# How to set is_user_logged_in() true in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am using `wp_signon` from inside a plugin and inside a shortcode function to login a user. To clarify, the short code is being called from a page content. The `wp_signon` function successfully returns the user info. But `is_user_logged_in()` is returning **false**. Why it's happening or how can I set `is_user_logged_in()` **true** so that user stays login?

```
            ob_start();
            $user_data = array();
            $user_data['user_login'] = $username;
            $user_data['user_password'] = $password;
            $user_data['remember'] = $remember;  
            $user = wp_signon( $user_data, false );
              ob_get_clean();
            if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
                $err = $user->get_error_message();

            } else {


                $_SESSION['fc_user']=$user->ID;
                var_dump($user); // gives the user info
                var_dump(is_user_logged_in()); // gives false

            }
```

Comment: You means users can't stays logged in your site? $remember needs true if you want to satys in this site. is_user_logged_in() will not work if you don't have any data into your session. wp_signon() will handle your session. But why in else condition you set $_SESSION['fc_user']? Did you start the session?

Comment: @Faysal yes I did start the session using session_start().

Comment: @FaysalHaque, I didn't understand what you meant by "$remember needs true". But I tried with wp_signon( $user_data, true ); as well. It still didn't work.

Comment: did you put this code inside a function called on the after_setup_theme hook, like explained [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon#Examples)?

Comment: @d79 no, it's inside a shortcode hook and I need this inside a shortcode hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`wp_signon`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

> sends headers to the page. It must be run before any content is returned.

So running it inside a shortcode (like you specified in your comment) is too late: headers have already been sent.

In order to achieve what you want you should divide your code in two parts, to be run at different time, something like this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {

    // run this only on the page you want
    if( !is_page('the_page_you_want') )
        return;

    $user_data = array();
    $user_data['user_login'] = $username;
    $user_data['user_password'] = $password;
    $user_data['remember'] = $remember;  
    $user = wp_signon( $user_data, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        $GLOBALS['user_error_message'] = $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['fc_user'] = $user->ID;
    }

} );


add_shortcode( 'your_shortcode', function( $atts ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // get user info
        return print_r( get_userdata(get_current_user_id()), 1 );
    } elseif( isset($GLOBALS['user_error_message']) ) {
        // show error
        return print_r( $GLOBALS['user_error_message'], 1 );
    }

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue with an MVC Wordpress plugin.
For me the solution was to include

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
```

to have access to the core function via a plugin.

Comment: That just makes an assumption that could be totally wrong. What if WordPress's core files are **not** in the server's document root?